# How to open a specific port in Mountain Lion Firewall

Tags: macos, firewall

I cant seem to find how to open a specific port in the ML firewall? I know you can give applications permission, but that's no good to me. Is there a way I can specify a specific port?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, and why allowing an application permissions doesn't solve it? If you don't have a program listening on that port, opening it in the firewall doesn't do any good; if you do have a program listening, just allow that program in the firewall.

Comment: I know it's an old question. Nonetheless I don't understand the downvote. The Op clearly asked what he was trying to achive: opening a port on the internal firewall. There are many reasons for this without the need of a specific application.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/how-can-i-open-a-port-not-application-in-the-os-x-10-6-firewall) explains how to open a port by using the terminal. Otherwise you will need to download a program such as [IceFloor](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_enhance_mac_os_x%E2%80%99s_firewall_icefloor) or [WaterRoof](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/) if you want a GUI.

Comment: That opens a port in the ipfw firewall, which is already wide open by default. In order to do anything useful, you have to be dealing with the application firewall (alf aka socketfilterfw aka a bunch of other names).

Answer (score 0):

There are two firewalls. The application firewall, and network layer firewall. The network firewall can be interacted with ipfw like this:

```
sudo ipfw list
sudo ipfw add [rule number] allow tcp from any to any dst-port [port]
```

You can interact with the application level firewall like this:

1. Open System Preferences.
2. Click the Security or Security & Privacy icon.
3. Select the Firewall tab.
4. Click the lock icon in the preference pane, then enter an administrator name and password.
5. Click the Firewall Options button
6. Click the Add Application (+) button. Select the app you want to allow incoming connection privileges for.
7. Click Add.
8. Click OK.

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201642

Enjoy.